# 401 - Unauthorized - Subcode 0?

Tags: sql-server-2008, http, iis, http-error, unauthorized

When browsing to a site hosted in IIS 7.5, we are getting

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

When reviewing the logs in inetpub, the follow two lines come up every attempt

```
2013-06-14 15:08:26 xxx.xxx.xxx.153 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.98 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/27.0.1453.110+Safari/537.36 401 0 0 265

2013-06-14 15:08:26 xxx.xxx.xxx.153 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.98 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/27.0.1453.110+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 78
```

My understanding is that the number after 401 is the subcode... but it shows 0.  According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;318380&x=17&y=8) there is no subcode 0.

What's going on here?

*i'm lost and confused, twisted and used, i know a better code existed, but think that i missed it*